# Cascode Input Impedance

Tags: input-impedance, cascode

Please see attached image. I struggling to understand why Rs is negelected in the input impedance; should'nt the total input impedance be the parrallel combination of the capacitor impedance with the Rpi **plus in series with Rs?**

[image: Cascode Input and Output Impedance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes !

In the referenced equation, Rs is not referenced. The capacitance is. Clearly the signal at the base of Q1 does depend on the value of Rs -- it is in series with the input signal, and there is (at least) a capacitance to GND.

A little inspection will show that the true impedance is Rs+...